# Displaying only features filtered in attribute table on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, filter

Having filtered features using the Attribute Table filter feature how do I display only those features and hide the rest on the Map screen? I can 'select' them so they are highlighted but I want to just display them on their own. I have seen suggestions for using the Query Builder in the Provider Feature Builder but it would seem useful to be able to filter them from the Attribute Table interface and see the results on the Map.